# Finding and Dropping the Negative values

Tags: python, pandas

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Zd7.png)

In this database i have, there are negative values in "Benefits", "OvertimePay" and "OtherPay"
How can i drop the rows that have negative values in any of those 3 columns ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close with `df[df['Benefits'] < 0]`. You need any of those 3 columns to have this so you can "or" them with `|`. But you want to drop so we put `~` beginnig to invert the condition and select others.

```
new = df[~((df['Benefits'] < 0) | (df['OvertimePay'] < 0) | (df['OtherPay'] < 0))].copy()
```

(i copy so you get not a view but a copy)

but there is a better way with `any`

```
new = df[~df[['Benefits', 'OvertimePay', 'OtherPay']].lt(0).any(axis=1)].copy()
```

`lt` is a method way of `<` (less than). `any(axis=1)` checks if any of the columns has less than 0.

maybe better to write two lines

```
drop_these = df[['Benefits', 'OvertimePay', 'OtherPay']].lt(0).any(axis=1)
new = df[~drop_these].copy()
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response.Thank you it was exactly what i was looking for.